# Using "this" with Event Delegation Jquery

Tags: jquery, event-delegation

I am trying to convert the following simple click event function into a delegated one. Can anyone help me out.

```
$(".click-slide").click(function(){
$(this).siblings().slideToggle();
$(this).find("button").toggleClass('uparrow');
});
```

This is what I've done so far, but all in vain

```
$(".refine-buttons .wd-210").on("click", ".click-slide",(function(){
    $(this).siblings().slideToggle();
    $(this).find("button").toggleClass('uparrow');
});
```

And the corresponding HTML is:

```
<div class="refine-buttons wd-210">
    <div class="btn-slide" id="term">
    <div class="click-slide">
        <button>Search Terms (0)</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-box">
        <label>Some thing</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-slide">
    <div class="click-slide">
        <button>Categories ()</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-box">
        <label>Other thing</label>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Mind you that the following is being added dynamically after DOM Ready**

```
<div class="btn-box">
    <label>Some thing</label>
</div>
```

I think the "this" keyword is causing the issue here. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: by the way where is element with class `refine-buttons` ?

Comment: @Mritunjay: That was a mistake, check the updated code.

Comment: your parent should be like this: `$(".refine-buttons.wd-210")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to this:

```
 $(this)
```

you don't need to have quotes in it.

and you can remove `(` from your callback:

```
$(".refine-buttons.wd-210").on("click", ".click-slide",(function(){
// this one--------------------------------------------^
```

Since your static parent has two classes then you don't need to have a *space* between them:

```
$(".refine-buttons.wd-210") // matches the parent div
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the `quotes` surrounded around `this`,

```
$(".refine-buttons .wd-210").on("click", ".click-slide",function(){
    $(this).siblings().slideToggle();
    $(this).find("button").toggleClass('uparrow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Are `.refine-buttons` and `.wd-210` created after the page is loaded?

If yes then you have to target an existing parent(grand-parent, etc) of `.click-slide`.

e.g

```
$("html body").on("click", ".click-slide",function(){
  $(this).siblings().slideToggle();
  $(this).find("button").toggleClass('uparrow');
});
```

And remove the quotes in `$("this")`, it should be `$(this)`